# Namespace constants and use as

Tags: php, namespaces, constants, alias

I'm having some problems with using constants from a namespace.  If I define the constant and try to use as it, PHP seems unable to find it.  For example, in my file with the constants I have code along the lines of the following:

```
namespace \my\namespace\for\constants;

const DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Then in the consuming file I have:

```
namespace \some\other\namespace;

use \my\namespace\for\constants\DS as DS;

echo (realpath (DS . 'usr' . DS 'local'));
```

However, instead of echoing '/usr/local' as expected I get the following notice and an empty string.

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS'

If I change the code as follows:

```
use \my\namespace\for\constants as cns;

echo (realpath (cns\DS . 'usr' . cns\DS 'local'));
```

I get the expected result, but it's obviously quite a bit less convenient than just being able to pull the constants in directly.

You can alias a class/interface/trait in a namespace, are you not able to alias a constant too?  If you can do it, then how?

Comment: a namespace and a constant is something different. The `use` command maps namespaces, not constants. You could use a define macro but I would consider that bad style: it reduces readability of the code, since it is not clear what that 'DS' is resolved to, where it comes from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read documentation carefully.

> PHP namespaces support three kinds of aliasing or importing: aliasing a class name, aliasing an interface name, and aliasing a namespace name. Note that importing a function or constant is not supported.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

```
// trying to import constant -- not supported
use \my\namespace\for\constants\DS as DS; 
// trying to import namespace -- it's works
use \my\namespace\for\constants as cns;
```

**UPDATE.**

> PHP 5.6+ also allows aliasing or importing function and constant
>   names.

Now you are able import constants.

Answer (score 13):

Support for importing functions and constants from namespaces was added in PHP 5.6:

```
namespace my\space;

const CONSTANT_NAME = 123;

function function_name() {
    echo "Test\n";
}

// elsewhere:
use function my\space\function_name;
function_name();

use function my\space\function_name as f;    
f();

use const my\space\CONSTANT_NAME;
echo CONSTANT_NAME . "\n";

use const my\space\CONSTANT_NAME as C;
echo C . "\n";
```

Note that in order to be importable, constants must be defined using `const` rather than `define`:

```
namespace my\space;

const CONSTANT_NAME = 123;    // this can be imported
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 123); // this sets a global constant
```

It is worthy to note that it is *not* possible to import class constants:

```
namespace my\space;

class Test {
    const CONSTANT_NAME = 123;
}

use const my\space\Test\CONSTANT_NAME;  // undefined constant
use const my\space\Test::CONSTANT_NAME; // syntax error
```